# FlushMode type Commit used with REQUIRES_NEW Transaction Attribute

Tags: ejb, cdi, seam3

I'm developing with JBoss 7.1.1 Final, Weld, Hibernate 4, Seam 3 and I don't understand following behavior. I use Seam Managed Persistence Context for Entity managers and Persistence Interceptor from Seam 3. I have following CDI Bean:

```
 @ViewScoped
 @Named
 public class RegistrationController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private RegisterService service;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public void register() {
          Person p = service.register("username","password");
          Person pp = em.find(Person.class, p.getId()); //returns null
    } 
 }
```

And following EJB

```
 @Stateless
 @Local(IRegisterService.class)
 public RegisterService implements IRegisterService {

      @Inject
      private EntityManager em;      

      @Override
      @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
      public Person register(String username, String password) {
           return em.merge(new Person(username, password));
      }
 }
```

So since I use Seam Persistence module I assume that this flow of operations will occur:

1) registrationController.register() is called from frontend

2) New transaction A is initiated

3) service.register(...) is called

4) Transaction A is suspended and transaction B is created for execution of service.register (since it is annotated by REQUIRES_NEW)

5) The execution service.register(...) is completed

6) Transaction B is committed

7) Since I use COMMIT flush type, flush will be called

8) Transaction A is opened back

Now, em.find(Person.class, p.getId()) is trying to find just persisted person. Since transaction B was committed and entity manager flushed, it should find it. But it returns null. If I do flush manually, then it works.

Where am I making mistake? Is there some misunderstanding?

Comment: Have you debugged the transactions? By `log4j.logger.org.jboss.seam.transaction=DEBUG` for instance if you are using log4J.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code I'd say - since `RegistrationController` is a ordinary managed bean - that it will **not** start its own transaction. This basically means that you have a single transaction B.

Comment: well but it is still supposed to commit (and therefore flush), before em.find(Person.class, p.getId()) in the managed bean is called. Moreover, I'm using Persistence module of Seam 3 so actually the transaction is started even in the managed bean automatically.

Comment: I see. Hm. I still reckon that the problem comes from unexpected transactional behaviour - I vaguely remember that there are dedicated logging options for transaction boundaries - this should take you one step further...

Comment: It seems that if I use SMPC in the service (EJB), it doesn't work but if I use @PersistenceContext to get my entitymanager, it works fine. I don't understand this behavior.